# Spring JPA - Method to remove a single child

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a Spring boot app using Spring JPA on a OneToMany database relationship. It is a skincare routine builder where a routine is made up of many products. I am trying to create a method to delete a single product from the routine based on the foreign key and name field of the product class any help would be much appreciated

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "routines")
public class Routine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type; 

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product.class, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "routine_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

child entity

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String category; // enum list : cleanser, toner, moisturiser, sunscreen, serum....

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String brand;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int size;

    @Column()
    private String review; // only show this in get all products tab??
}
```

small snippet of my controller

```
 @DeleteMapping("{id}/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteRoutineProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long routineId, @PathVariable("name") String name){

        productService.deleteProduct(routineId, productName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Product deleted successfully.",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I have tried orphanRemoval and a few methods from guides but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `Routine` class to include a method that searches and removes a product based on the product name:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "routines")
public class Routine {

    // ... (other fields)

    public void removeProductByName(String productName) {
        products.removeIf(product -> product.getName().equals(productName));
    }

    // ... (getters and setters)
}
```

Then, update your controller to utilize the method from the `Routine` class and call it when deleting a product:

```java
@DeleteMapping("{id}/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteRoutineProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long routineId, @PathVariable("name") String name){

    Optional<Routine> optionalRoutine = routineRepository.findById(routineId);

    if (optionalRoutine.isPresent()) {
        Routine routine = optionalRoutine.get();
        routine.removeProductByName(name);
        routineRepository.save(routine);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Product deleted successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Routine not found.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

By using the `removeProductByName` method within your `Routine` class, you can remove a specific product by name from the list of products associated with the routine.